# Where can I get 1/x as a single character as is ½?

Tags: unicode, character, special-characters

Following is the image which I wanted to have as a character:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are some additional fractions such as ⅔ in Unicode, there's no 1/x or 1/y. There's a ⅟ symbol, though. (U+215F)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can live with that.